# Get Date and Month by using a number in JAVA

Tags: java, date, calendar

I want to get the date and month by using a given number. How can I do that with calendar class easily?

example : 079 is march 19.

Comment: Any attempt so far ?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Please read on [Calendar API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) precisely -> [Day of year] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_YEAR)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like that:

```
 Calendar localCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
 localCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 79);
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 String formatted = sdf.format(localCalendar.getTime());
 System.out.println(formatted);
```

This will output "2015-03-20".

Comment: Thank you very much. My question has solved because of you..thank again. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this is one :

```
      // Get the year, month, day, hour, minute, second   
      import java.util.Calendar;
      public class GetYMDHMS {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        // You cannot use Date class to extract individual Date fields
       int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
       int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);      // 0 to 11
       int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
       int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
       int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
       int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

      System.out.printf("Now is %4d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n",  // Pad with zero
      year, month+1, day, hour, minute, second);
  }
  }
```

Comment: 079 is march 19.   if you write condition to given number than match calendar Methods ....

Comment: Thank you very much mr/miss/mrs. vishnu